# getter method and two classes

Tags: java, methods, parameters, get

I want to understand the getter method.

In my first class i have a get method and a parameter.

In the second class I amde a new object with a parameter. Now i want to print out this value with the getter method, but the console is printing 0 and not 23?

Here is my code

First class:

```
public class CopyOfHeld {

    private int LP;

    public CopyOfHeld(int pLP) {             
        pLP = LP;      
    }


    public int getLp() {
        return LP;
    }
}
```

and second class:

```
public class CopyOfKampfregel {

    public CopyOfKampfregel()  {

        CopyOfHeld held1 = new CopyOfHeld(23);        
        System.out.println(held1.getLp());         
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is on a nuts and bolts issue of most basic Java, and that you're getting your setter method's assignment backwards suggests that it would greatly benefit you to check out the intro to Java tutorials. Please check out [Oracle Java Tutorial Big Index site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it prints 0 has to do with the way you assign the constructor passed in value.

When you create a new `CopyOfHeld` object you pass in a primitive `int` value which you attempt to assign this way: `pLP = LP;`.

Problem is that instead of assigning the actual passed in value to the instance field like so `LP = pLP;` you do the exact opposite, thus assigning the `LP` field. Since this is a primitive `int` it's default value is 0, hence why you get 0 when you attempt to print it out.

Changing you assignment and fixing it will correct this issue.

Comment: wow thank you. I didnt know that this makes a different. It is working!